# Rails Validates Prevents Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :password, :presence => true,
                         :confirmation => true,
                         :length => { :within => 6..40 }
    .
    .
    .
end
```

In the User model, I have a billing_id column I want to save into from a OrdersController which looks like this:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    .
    .
    .
    def create
        @order = Order.new(params[:order])
        if @order.save
            if @order.purchase
                response = GATEWAY.store(credit_card, options)
                result = response.params['billingid']
                @thisuser = User.find(current_user)
                @thisuser.billing_id  = result
                if @thisuser.save
                        redirect_to(root_url), :notice => 'billing id saved')
                    else
                        redirect_to(root_url), :notice => @thisuser.errors)
                    end
            end
        end
    end
```

Because of `validates :password` in the User model, `@thisuser.save` doesn't save. However, once I comment out the validation, `@thisuser.save` returns true. This is an unfamiliar territory for me because I thought this validation only worked when creating a new User. Can someone tell me if `validates :password` is supposed to kick in each time I try to save in User model? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify when you want to run your validations otherwise they will be run on every `save` call. This is easy to limit, though:

```
validates :password,
  :presence => true,
  :confirmation => true,
  :length => { :within => 6..40 },
  :on => :create
```

An alternative is to have this validation trigger conditionally:

```
validates :password,
  :presence => true,
  :confirmation => true,
  :length => { :within => 6..40 },
  :if => :password_required?
```

You define a method that indicates if a password is required before this model can be considered valid:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def password_required?
    # Validation required if this is a new record or the password is being
    # updated.
    self.new_record? or self.password?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you are validating that the password has been confirmed (`:confirmation => true`), but the password_confirmation does not exist.

You can break this out to something like:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :length => { :within => 6..40 }
validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_changed?
```

I like this approach because if the user ever changes their password, it will require the user entered the same password_confirmation.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, this is tremendously useful