# determining proper place for password_required? with a before_save password encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following model and am trying to turn off password validation for the User model using this [Rails Validates Prevents Save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600297/rails-validates-prevents-save)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :encrypt_password
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                   :confirmation => true,
                   :length => { :within => 4..12 },
                   :if => :password_required?

  def password_required?        
    self.new_record? or self.password?
  end

  #
  # where we encrypt on creation
  #
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
```

I get an error for:

```
undefined method `password?' for #<User:0x007fc8e0473be0>
```

Should I just check for self.password_hash? There's another form for updating the password. What is the best strategy for turning off validation in that instance?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to your user model:

```
attr_accessor :password
```

That will give your user model a password attribute -- however, it is not persisted to the database or remember in your application in any way. Only the salt and hash are stored.

To get password? in your model too, do this:

```
attr_accessor :password
alias :password? :password
```

You can use `password?` like a gimpy Boolean field: if it returns anything, then password is set. Otherwise password hasn't been set.

Comment: thx, this makes sense but still getting an error `undefined method `password?' for #<User:0x007fc8e05da5b0>`. Noob at rails. Is the syntax for self.password? off